# Как взаимодействуют float и absolute?

Tags: css, float, position, language-lawyer

При помощи `float: left` расположим подряд несколько дивов в строку, а перед каждым из них добавим кнопку и пропишем ей `position: absolute`: 
https://jsfiddle.net/v4xjy9d3/2/

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, silver, blue);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<div></div>
<button>Button</button>
<div></div>
<button>Button</button>
<div></div>
```

В хроме блоки встают подряд, а кнопка накладывается на каждый из блоков. А вот Firefox сначала расставил все float'ы, а потом аналогично тексту разместил все кнопки после них одну поверх другой. Кто из браузеров прав в данном случае?

[image: скриншоты]

PS: Как исправить я и сам знаю - обернуть каждую пару в блок, которому и ставить float. Интересно именно узнать, какое поведение верное.

Comment: Интереса ради попробовал Opera 12 (Presto) — ведёт себя как хром

Answer (score 2):

Кнопки позиционируются абсолютно, но для них не указаны `left`, `right` и `width`. Когда все три этих параметра оказываются `auto` (их значение по умолчанию), спецификация предписывает рассчитать их так, чтобы абсолютно спозиционированный элемент оказался там же, где бы он был при `position: static` и `float: none`.

Такое положение элемента называется "[static position](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#static-position)":

> the term "static position" (of an element) refers, roughly, to the position an element would have had in the normal flow

Чтобы представить себе "статичное положение" для каждой кнопки, удобно рассмотреть их по очереди:

1. Первая кнопка, если прописать ей `position: static; float: none`, окажется в левом верхнем углу контейнера.
2. Вторая - справа от первого плавающего блока.
3. Третья - справа от двух первых плавающих блоков.

Получается, хром и эксплорер показывают как раз это "статичное положение" для каждой из кнопок, а файерфокс неправ.

Comment: Но static position для inline-элементов рассчитывается после всех float'ов, а значит, либо ответ неполный, либо прав как раз-таки FF? А ещё есть интересный момент, если к кнопке добавить display: block. Хром поставит все кнопки в начало, а вот лис почему-то не всегда - тут уже похоже на лисий косяк с проверкой необходимости пересчитать положение при изменении.

Comment: Мне кажется, чтобы получить статичное положение надо рассмотреть **только предшествующих** плавающих блоков.

Comment: Ну, мне тоже так _кажется,_ а оно где-то прописано?)

Comment: Думаю, очередность расчета задаёт тем, что кнопка все-таки абсолютно позиционирована, а не инлайн. А вот, чтобы понять её "статичное положение", воображаем себе, будто она в обычном потоке. Из этого мне кажется, что кнопку считаем так, как будто после нее ничего нет, и последующие плавающие блоки не вмешиваются Но похоже ребята из файерфокса решили по-другому.

Comment: Так именно поэтому я вопрос и задал :)